# Neat Diophantine Equation Question

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

After some fairly tedious work including studying multiple different cases separately, I have found all the solutions to 
$$a^n+1=b^2 $$ where $a$, $b$, $n$ can take on the value of any integer, be it positive, negative or zero. I just wanted to see how MSE users would solve it perhaps there are easier and more elegant approaches.

(Note: I consider using Catalan's Conjecture at any stage of the argument to be "cheating". )

Answer (score 0):

if $a=2,n=3,b=3$ is only solution. Indeed if $n=2k+1$ we use Zsigmondy's theorem 
$$a^n+1=b^2$$ 
have no solution
see [Zsigmondy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem)

Comment: still "cheating" :P sorry

Comment: Hello,I don't undestand your meaning

Comment: @Assaultous2, it's a little bit smug to call on cheating when people are trying to answer your "challenge" question.

Comment: your not proving anything just using an already proven result

Comment: sorry iHubble, but if your using a result which basically proves the case it doesnt show me how the proof works

Comment: How exactly are you using Zsigmondy's theorem?

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

$$a^n=b^2-1=(b-1)(b+1)$$

$(b+1,b-1)=(b+1,2)$

**Case** $\#1:$ If $a$ is odd, $b\pm1$ are odd,  $(b+1,b-1)=1$

**Case** $\#2:$

If $a$ is even,  $b\pm1$ are even $\implies n\ge2$ and   $$\frac{a^n}4=\frac{b-1}2\cdot\frac{b+1}2$$

and $$\left(\frac{b-1}2,\frac{b+1}2\right)=1$$

Comment: if $(b-1/2,b+1/2)=1$ then following is ?

Comment: @math110, Factorize $\dfrac{a^n}4=p\cdot q$ where $(p,q)=1$

Comment: I know, so I think is very ugly

Comment: Why is it impossible for one of $(b\pm 1)/2$ to be an $n$th power of an odd integer, say $r^n$ and the other be of the form $2^{n-2}s^n$ with $\gcd(r,s)=1$. It is clear that $r^n$ and $s^n$ cannot be consecutive integers (which handles the case of an odd $a$), but why would the same hold for $r^n$ and $2^{n-2}s^n$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, All we need is $$(2^{n-2}s^n, r^n)=1$$

Comment: Full details, please. Exactly what is the contradiction when, for example, $(b+1)/2=2r^3$ and $(b-1)/2=s^3$. You arrive at $2r^3=s^3+1$. Why is that (and the other cases) impossible. Without that factor $2$ it is, of course, trivial.